# The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, wcf

I'm trying to make a cross domain jQuery ajax call to a wcf service. I tried it with one service which takes no parameters and returns data. It works fine. But when I try to call a wcf service with parameters it's causing the below error:

```
The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'
```

Here is the service code:

```
public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
```

Here is the operation contract:

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    string GetData(int value);
```

and here is the jQuery AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://10.1.2.167:99/Service1.svc/GetData',
            data: JSON.stringify({ "value": 1 }),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
```

Can any one point out what may be wrong....

Comment: Try adding contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json", to the Ajax parameters

Comment: @artm it gives the following error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) `

Comment: Do you get the definition of the wcf when you put http://10.1.2.167:99/Service1.svc in a browser?